# Separate a single word in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a word like this.

London Hethrew Airport (LHR) and I want to split this word as London Hethrew Airport and LHR.

Can I use regular expression like this?

```
^[A-Za-z\w\s]{([a-z A-z]\)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't you simple split on the first bracket?

```
var dataArray="London Hethrew Airport (LHR)".Split("(");
dataArray[0]=dataArray[0].trim();
dataArray[1]=dataArray[1].replace(")","").trim();
```

Niko

Answer (score 2):

You can match that string with a regex like:

```
^([^(]+)\s+\(([A-Z]+)\)$
```

Explanation:

```
  ^                        the beginning of the string
  (                        group and capture to \1:
    [^(]+                    any character except: '(' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
  )                        end of \1
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
  \(                       '('
  (                        group and capture to \2:
    [A-Z]+                   any character of: 'A' to 'Z' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
  )                        end of \2
  \)                       ')'
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: Or rather `^(.+)\s+\(([A-Z]+)\)`

Comment: Great explanation but the second capture group doesn't want to match the brackets

Comment: @phuzi Seems to work fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Sw23W/ Can you give me more information on what is wrong?

Comment: This solution will capture `London Hethrow Airport` and `(LHR)` but OP asked for `London Hethrow Airport` and `LHR`.